# How do I remove a Weak<T> value from a BinaryHeap if it fails to upgrade to a strong reference?

Tags: rust, priority-queue, weak

I would like to use a `BinaryHeap` with elements of type `MyWrapperStruct(Weak<MyStruct>)`, where I implement `Ord` for `MyWrapperStruct`. In this implementation, I need to upgrade the weak references, which might fail. If they fail, I want the element to be removed from the heap.

How could I implement this in a way that doesn't require me to traverse the entire heap first to remove all the non-upgradable weak references? There will be a large amount of data in this heap, while only very few of these will become invalid. For the sake of performance, I would like to avoid traversal of all data.

Comment: I expanded my answer to include the reason for wanting to avoid traversal of the entire data structure. I don't know how to give an example; it should be clear that the implementation of `Ord` requires upgrading weak references, which might fail.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove an item while you are comparing something.

Also, from my point of view, implementing `Ord` would be wrong for the same reason why `Ord` is not implemented for floating-point values in Rust. If you have two non-upgradable `Weak` structures, there is no order between them and that's the reason why `PartialOrd` exists.

If you really want to make your example work, implement `Ord` for your type and order non-upgradable `Weak`s at the very top (e.g. it is always the biggest element), then use `peek` on your `BinaryHeap` to check if it is upgradable; if not, remove it and take the next one.
This is a nasty hack but probably your best solution if you want your thing to work.

Comment: Ah I forget that the state can change at anytime so indeed use a binaryheap is not at all a good idea.

Comment: The problem I see with your suggesting implementing `Ord` is that when a `Weak` expires (that is, its referent is destroyed) its relative order to the rest of the heap changes, and that is against the [`BinaryHeap` contract](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html): _It is a logic error for an item to be modified in such a way that the item's ordering relative to any other item, as determined by the Ord trait, changes while it is in the heap._